# How to replicate Apache custom two-factor authentication on IIS?

Tags: iis, authentication

I've set up a small test server that does custom two-factor authentication on Apache, using a mechanism similar to this:

In `<VirtualHost>` file (of course, there are lots of other settings!):

```
<Location /2factor>
    PerlAccessHandler Apache::TicketAccess
    ErrorDocument     403 /perl/login.pl
</Location>
```

So, when I try to access a file in the `/2factor` directory I get redirected to a login script where I verify a user, password and TOTP from Google Authenticator, if an appropriate cookie is not present. This all works perfectly from both a browser and a smartphone app.

I've been asked to move this code to IIS, but all the example code I see uses either the browser's built-in authentication or LDAP-based solutions. How should I approach this? I'm not wedded to Perl; a C#-based method is perfectly acceptable.

Note, my test environment is just IIS 5.1 and XP.